# how Can I put numbers on map instead of generic markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

in google maps how can weput numbers on map instead of generic (if multiple number of icons listed means number have to increment like 1,2,3 )

instead of

```
  var iconBlue = new GIcon(); 
iconBlue.image = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
iconBlue.shadow = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png';
iconBlue.iconSize = new GSize(12, 20);
iconBlue.shadowSize = new GSize(22, 20);
iconBlue.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 20);
iconBlue.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 1);
```

is this possible in google maps ???
here i found some link but it's not working.

Comment: You are using the deprecated (and turned off) [Gooogle Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).  New code should be developed in the [currently active v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with the current API (v3) - but you can use the [StyledMarker Library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/reference.html). It extends the `marker` class and allows you to style the icon and put text inside the icons if you want as well (which is what I believe you're looking for). Just include the script in your application (after you load the Maps API script). And then add the `StyledMarker` like you would the regular `marker` object:

```
var styleMaker1 = new StyledMarker({
    styleIcon: new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER, {
        color: "FFFFFF",
        text: "1" //this is where you'll set your incremented value
    }),
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
});
```

Here's a fiddle of how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/7L2wY/